# Closure call with mismatched arguments using DateTime

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I'm a designer dipping my toes on programming by following a tutorial. It's supposed to be an app that saves and shows transactions made within the last week. But I'm getting this error message whenever I try to add a transaction on the app. It throws me this error:

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_MyHomePageState._addNewTransaction'
Receiver: Closure: (String, double) => void from Function '_addNewTransaction@17043806':.
Tried calling: _MyHomePageState._addNewTransaction("Wednesday", 555.0, Instance of 'DateTime')
Found: _MyHomePageState._addNewTransaction(String, double) => void
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

In simple terms, how could I fix this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function addTx;
  NewTransaction(this.addTx);

  @override
  State<NewTransaction> createState() => _NewTransactionState();
}

class _NewTransactionState extends State<NewTransaction> {
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final _amountController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime _selectedDate;

  void _submitData() {
    if (_amountController.text.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    final enteredTitle = _titleController.text;
    final enteredAmount = double.parse(_amountController.text);

    if (enteredTitle.isEmpty || enteredAmount <= 0 || _selectedDate == null) {
      return;
    }

    widget.addTx(
      enteredTitle,
      enteredAmount,
      _selectedDate,
    );

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void _presentDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2023),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    ).then((pickedDate) {
      if (pickedDate == null) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = pickedDate;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
              controller: _titleController,
              onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
              controller: _amountController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  child: Text(
                    _selectedDate == null
                        ? 'No Date Chosen'
                        : 'Picked Date: ${DateFormat.MEd().format(_selectedDate)}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                    child: Text(
                      'Choose Date',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    onPressed: _presentDatePicker)
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 60,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                    foregroundColor:
                        Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge.color,
                    textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                onPressed: _submitData,
                child: Text('Add transaction'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## What I've tried and sort of "worked"

It seems to run when I delete `_selectedDate` from the widget.addTx but without it, it won't save the transaction with the correct date.

## What is supposed to happen

The problem occurs when I tap the Add Transaction button, it's supposed to save the transaction and show it on a list. But I can't seem to actually add a transaction since I've implemented the selectedDate parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to a mismatch between how the `addTx` function is *called* and how the function passed in is actually *defined*. The number and/or types of arguments do not match.

Since you have not provided an example of how `NewTransaction()` is used, the best way to get to the bottom is to declare `addTx` more precisely.

Instead of

```dart
final Function addTx;
```

Declare it as

```dart
final void Function(String, double, DateTime) addTx;
```

Then you should see a static type-checking error at any location that passes in the incorrect function type.

See also [PREFER signatures in function type annotations](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-signatures-in-function-type-annotations).

Comment: Worked like a charm! I even used diffchecker between my code and the tutorial's and it was the same, must be from an older version maybe. It worked and even threw the error you mentioned, but after clearing the console it didn't appear again. I'm still confused on why the error appeared in the first place though. Since I declared all 3 parameters but the error stated I only declared two.

Comment: @Vegnecios Great, glad it helped! Perhaps it was a hot-reload issue? As a hypothetical example: while you were following the tutorial and editing, the function definition initially had only two parameters; this code was hot reloaded; then you added a third parameter; but the code did not hot reload after that; when the `addTx()` call was made, there were only actually two parameters in the loaded code. Just one possible explanation that comes to mind.